# What to look for in the ARM64 assembly of a Golang binary to find the list of kill signals that affect the binary execution?

Tags: arm64

I'm reverse engineering an `ARM64` Golang binary built with `musl` and I've already detected `kill -10,12,15 pid` as the signals which interact with it, where `10` and `12` represent user-defined signals. I think there must be other signals as well and I wish to detect them. In particular, may there be other user-defined signals or only 2 `SIGUSR`s are available no matter what? Since signals are being sent to the binary during runtime I wanted to know if there are signature functions in Golang's runtime that may be imported in the binary and represent signal handling functionalities in the binary.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally only two signals are reserved for users - `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`. But there are possibilities for others as well as mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48582/why-there-are-only-two-user-defined-signals/48594).

I would check if the signals `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2` does anything besides the obvious, like maybe call other subroutines.